# How can pg_column_size be smaller than octet_length?

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for getting anticipated table size by referring column type and length size. I'm trying to use `pg_column_size` for this.

When testing the function, I realized something seems wrong with this function.

The result value from `pg_column_size(...)` is sometimes even smaller than the return value from `octet_length(...)` on the same string.

There is nothing but numeric characters in the column.

```
postgres=# \d+ t5
                           Table "public.t5"
 Column |       Type        | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 c1     | character varying |           | extended |              | 
Has OIDs: no

postgres=# select pg_column_size(c1), octet_length(c1) as octet from t5;
 pg_column_size | octet 
----------------+-------
              2 |     1
            704 |   700
            101 |  7000
            903 | 77000
(4 rows)
```

Is this the bug or something? Is there someone with the some formula to calculate anticipated table size from column types and length values of it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd say `pg_column_size` is reporting the compressed size of `TOAST`ed values, while `octet_length` is reporting the uncompressed sizes. I haven't verified this by checking the function source or definitions, but it'd make sense, especially as strings of numbers will compress quite well. You're using `EXTENDED` storage so the values are eligible for `TOAST` compression. See [the `TOAST` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html).

As for calculating expected DB size, that's whole new question. As you can see from the following demo, it depends on things like how compressible your strings are.

Here's a demonstration showing how `octet_length` can be bigger than `pg_column_size`, demonstrating where TOAST kicks in. First, let's get the results on query output where no `TOAST` comes into play:

```
regress=> SELECT octet_length(repeat('1234567890',(2^n)::integer)), pg_column_size(repeat('1234567890',(2^n)::integer)) FROM generate_series(0,12) n;
 octet_length | pg_column_size 
--------------+----------------
           10 |             14
           20 |             24
           40 |             44
           80 |             84
          160 |            164
          320 |            324
          640 |            644
         1280 |           1284
         2560 |           2564
         5120 |           5124
        10240 |          10244
        20480 |          20484
        40960 |          40964
(13 rows)
```

Now let's store that same query output into a table and get the size of the stored rows:

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE blah AS SELECT repeat('1234567890',(2^n)::integer) AS data FROM generate_series(0,12) n;
SELECT 13

regress=> SELECT octet_length(data), pg_column_size(data) FROM blah;
 octet_length | pg_column_size 
--------------+----------------
           10 |             11
           20 |             21
           40 |             41
           80 |             81
          160 |            164
          320 |            324
          640 |            644
         1280 |           1284
         2560 |             51
         5120 |             79
        10240 |            138
        20480 |            254
        40960 |            488
(13 rows)
```