# PostgreSQL select result size

Tags: select, postgresql-9.1

I have a table in PostgreSQL DB and make a select from this table with some constraints, and than I want to know how much disk space does this select has. I know that there is a postgres function `pg_total_relation_size` that gives me the size of some table in DB, but how can I find the 'subtable' size?

Any Ideas?

I use PostgreSQL 9.1

Comment: A select statement does not have a "disk size", because it's not stored anywhere.

Comment: Ok, so I need to store it first to get the size? Are there some other alternatives? I mean, I just want to know the size of a subtable...

Comment: You could spool it into a text file to get a rough estimate of the raw size of the data

Comment: I've just found the following alternative:                       `select sum(octet_length(temp.*::text)) from (select * from lesson) as temp`                                                                 It works and I get the size of the table in text represantation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get the data size, allowing for `TOAST` compression, etc:

```
regress=> SELECT sum(pg_column_size(devices)) FROM devices WHERE country = 'US';
 sum 
-----
 105
(1 row)
```

To get the disk storage required including block allocation overhead, headers, etc etc:

```
regress=> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE query_out AS SELECT * FROM devices WHERE country = 'US';
SELECT 3
regress=> SELECT pg_total_relation_size('query_out');
 pg_total_relation_size 
------------------------
                  16384
(1 row)
```

Why are the results so different? Because the latter query is reporting the size of the 8k block for the main table, and the 8k block for the TOAST table. It doesn't care that these blocks are mostly empty.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I looked for, the `octet_length` is also ok, but it gives me the number of bytes in binary string, so I'll get wrong size if the string is just a text...

Comment: @ann octet_length also won't reflect the space use from TOAST accurately. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304572/how-can-pg-column-size-be-smaller-than-octet-length

Comment: 16384? What does this mean? Is it in kb or bytes ?

Comment: @MohdAnas Well, the manual for `pg_total_relation_size` says bytes. So I guess it's bytes. If you want it pretty printed use `pg_size_pretty`

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks... Could you please tell me what I need to do if I want to get the size of multiple table in one query?

Comment: @MohdAnas Join on `pg_class`, or specify multiple table names manually, or use a `VALUES` list. Same as any other kind of query, really.

Comment: @CraigRinger, Can you be please write a sample query?

Comment: @MohdAnas If you are stuck after trying it yourself, please post a new question. Please link back to this one for context when you do so.

Comment: @CraigRinger, Here is my question please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054654/get-the-size-of-multiple-tables-in-one-query-postgres