# Get the Size of Multiple Tables in One Query POSTGRES?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

[Following on from this prior question about relation sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483895/398670):

This query:

```
query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE query_out AS SELECT * FROM users WHERE is_admin = false"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

will generate a temporary table and insert all the records from this query i.e

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE is_admin = false
```

then

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('query_out'))")
```

I am only getting the the size of one table.

What  doI need to do so that I can the size of multiple tables in one single query?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

It will give the size of that temporary table.

Comment: only specific number of tables or what ???

Comment: a guess : `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('table1')) size_table1,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('table2')) size_table2` like this you can try

Comment: yes there are specific number of table

Comment: Thanks, it is giving the size of tables in but in different columns. I need the size sum all tables?

Comment: Thanks, But its very complicated. I got the size of all tables but in different columns. Please suggest me a simple query so that I can sum up the size of the different columns.

Comment: You just create view in database and simply call `SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(size)) tablesizesum FROM vTableAndSize_1 WHERE mytable in ('table1','table2')` in the front end to get the size else you just workout to get a better solution for your case(I think you already get the idea from my answer )

Answer (score 3):

Following select query will returns all the table and its size's

```
SELECT
   relname as mytable,
   pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid)) As size
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

Create a VIEW with this select

```
CREATE VIEW vTableAndSize AS 
SELECT
   relname as mytable,
   pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid)) As size
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

and now you can query on this view to get the size like this

```
SELECT mytable,size 
       FROM vTableAndSize WHERE mytable in ('table1','table2')
```

---

As per [OP's Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054654/get-the-size-of-multiple-tables-in-one-query-postgres/27054810#comment42626082_27054654)

```
CREATE VIEW vTableAndSize_1 as 
SELECT
   relname as mytable,
   (pg_relation_size(relid)) As size
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

and get the size sum of multiple columns using

```
/* Get sum of specific tables */
SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(size)) tablesizesum 
       FROM vTableAndSize_1 WHERE mytable in ('table1','table2')

/* Get sum of all tables */
SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(size)) tablesizesum 
       FROM vTableAndSize_1
```

---

Create `vTableAndSize_1` in your `PostgreSQL` database and query like below in your front end(*am not familiar with `Ruby`*)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(size)) FROM vTableAndSize_1 
WHERE mytable in ('table1','table2')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will returns sum of two tables with union,split_part and sum functions.

```
select sum(sizeByte) from (select split_part(pg_size_pretty(hypertable_size('table1')), ' ', 1)::bigint *
case split_part(pg_size_pretty(hypertable_size('table1')), ' ', 2)
  when 'bytes' then 1
  when 'kB' then 1024
  when 'MB' then 1024*1024
  when 'GB' then 1024*1024*1024
  when 'TB' then 1024*1024*1024*1024::bigint
end as sizeByte
union
select split_part(pg_size_pretty(hypertable_size('table2')), ' ', 1)::bigint *
case split_part(pg_size_pretty(hypertable_size('table2')), ' ', 2)
  when 'bytes' then 1
  when 'kB' then 1024
  when 'MB' then 1024*1024
  when 'GB' then 1024*1024*1024
  when 'TB' then 1024*1024*1024*1024::bigint
end as sizeByte) t;
```