# How can I find out how big a large TEXT field is in Postgres?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, compression, zip

I'm storing some large XML documents in TEXT fields in Postgres and I'm trying to find out how efficiently TOAST is compressing them.  I've got a 2.2mb XML doc that is able to be zipped down to 51kb so I want to understand how close the compression ratio of TOAST can match it to make a final decision on how I'll be archiving these documents over time.

Is there a function in Postgres that will allow me to identify the TOAST compressed size of a specific column and row like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want `pg_column_size` for TOASTed size, `octet_length` for untoasted size. `pg_column_size` is in the [system administration functions section of the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html). See the docs and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13304572/398670) for more details.

Example:

```
craig=> CREATE TABLE toastdemo(x text);
CREATE TABLE
craig=> insert into toastdemo(x) select * from  repeat('abcdef',1000);
INSERT 0 1
craig=> select pg_column_size(x), pg_column_size(repeat('abcdef',1000)) FROM toastdemo;
 pg_column_size | pg_column_size 
----------------+----------------
             84 |           6004
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks! Based on these numbers it's very comparable.  It compressed a 2.2mb document down to 81kb which is perfect for my needs compared to dealing with externally stored zip files.

Comment: @aramisbear That's about what I'd expect; TOAST uses a simple LZ-flavour compression scheme with low CPU cost no unexpired patents and a relatively low compression ratio. There's been discussion of moving to deflate (the usual scheme used by zip and gzip) in future, but you're getting a good enough result with the existing scheme by the sounds.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually inspect the file:

```
SELECT oid AS table_name, reltoastrelid AS toast_tbl_name
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  oid = 'mytbl'::regclass
```

This produces the OIDs of the table and the toast table associated with it (if one exists). They serve as file names in the file system in your data directory. You can just go and look them up. In your data directory:

```
find . -name '216738'
```

And here's a quote from [the manual about the compression technique](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-toast.html):

> The compression technique used is a fairly simple and very fast member
>   of the LZ family of compression techniques. See
>   `src/backend/utils/adt/pg_lzcompress.c` for the details.